# Estate tax in the USA for non-residents

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, non-resident, estate

I read that the estate tax for non-residents on their US assets can go up to 40% with the first $60000 tax exempt. Suppose, as a non-resident, I have a brokerage account holding US stocks with the Indian arm of a US broker. Will this account be subject to US estate tax laws or Indian estate tax laws for my beneficiary after I die?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/some-nonresidents-with-us-assets-must-file-estate-tax-returns

Deceased nonresidents who were not American citizens are subject to U.S. estate taxation with respect to their U.S.-situated assets.

U.S.-situated assets include American real estate, tangible personal property, and securities of U.S. companies. **A nonresident’s stock holdings in American companies are subject to estate taxation even though the nonresident held the certificates abroad or registered the certificates in the name of a nominee.**

So the answer is that my account will be subject to US estate tax laws.

Answer (score 0):

You will be subject to the laws of whichever country you are a tax resident of. Simply owning US stocks does not make you a tax resident of the United States. Normally, in order to be a tax resident of the United States, you have to live and work in the United States to be a tax resident here. [The IRS has published guidelines to help determine US tax residency status.](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/determining-alien-tax-status#:%7E:text=More%20In%20File&text=You%20are%20a%20resident%20alien,and%20Ending%20Dates%20for%20aliens.)

Stocks in U.S. companies are considered "US-situated assets" no matter whether they are held by a foreign or domestic broker and are therefore subject to US estate taxes according to current law.

Comment: I know I am a non-resident. For non-residents the US estate tax of ~40% applies after an exemption of $60000 unless there is an estate tax treaty - and there is none between India and the USA. https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/some-nonresidents-with-us-assets-must-file-estate-tax-returns

Comment: If you think I am mistaken, please do point out the mistake and I will either modify or delete my answer.

Comment: @user2371765 You are right. I had no idea such a ridiculous law was in place. Obviously there would be difficulties enforcing such a law. Apparently the IRS does consider the estates of foreign persons taxable if they have US stocks in them.

Comment: It's extremely disappointing. Even India does not have estate tax. We have a saying which when literally translated into English means "Eating butter off a corpse's forehead". This is what the USA is doing through this law, and just because the person is non-resident. The IRS will surely find a way to get its pound of flesh because the broker is US-based. The IRS does not have any claim over non-US assets.